# knockout js using mapping - add records to observable array

Tags: knockout.js, append, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a viewModel created using the mapping plugin that looks something like this:

```
var ViewModel = function (config) {
    var self = this;
    self.datalog = ko.observableArray([]); 

    // Operations

    self.addData = function (x) {
        self.datalog.push(x());
        return x();
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(config, {}, self);
};
```

with a config data structure like:

```
{
  "result": {
    "stuff": [
      {
        "foo": "bar",
        "data": "Fred",
      },
      {
        "foo": "baz",
        "data": "Silvia",
      }
    ],
    "otherstuff": [
    ]
  }
}
```

periodically, new data comes in.  I have successfully mapped the array inside "stuff" to a table using a foreach binding, however the default behavior is that when new data comes in, it replaces the old data.  I would also like to have a different display where the behavior is that new data gets appended to an existing array rather than replace (there is no need to delete it currently).  I have tried creating an independent observable array and using a function (addData is called from a binding in the html as follows) to push the data there (that is what I am attempting the shown viewmodel).

```
// the following part of the page is intended to have replace functionality, 
//I am trying to use the event to push/append the data to a different array
<ol data-bind="foreach: $root.addData.bind($data, $data.result.stuff)">
    <li data-bind="text: $data.foo"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: $data.data"></li>
</ol>
```

The model binds properly, but doesn't work (no errors). I'm not sure if the problem is that addData isn't getting called because of the way I bound it, or whether the underlying approach is wrong.

Was wondering if someone knew an easy way to change the default behavior of the bindings in the mapping function to achieve append functionality, rather than the default replace.

UPDATE: I took a different approach - realizing I need to call a function on an event that will trigger the push, I just called it from the websockets onmessage handler.  It wont make any sense from what I wrote here - hence different approach.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. If you want to append data you would use an array and just push onto the array. You shouldn't really bind the foreach to the addData function. Just bind the foreach to the stuff array.

Comment: I realize its kind of confusing, sorry about that. When the data comes in, it's mapped to observables created by the mapping plugin.  Essentially I need to push/append data from part of the structure, and leave the rest as observables to update/replace.  If I could do that, I wouldn't need to bind the addData function as shown - that was just my unsuccessful attempt to push it.  Basically I don't know how to call a push event for part of a map, driven by new data from the server.

Comment: So you can just extend the model using the mapping plugin using: ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self); http://jsfiddle.net/9wsd4/ Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you're not expecting an answer to this, you should delete it, so it doesn't show up in the unanswered question list.

Comment: @Wayne, not really.  It's my fault for being unclear.  I am trying to make a sticky array that gets appended to.  I accomplished it by binding a function to the data source (a websocket) and pushing to the array directly, outside the mapping bindings.  I marked your answer as helpful though - and will play around with the fiddle you created to look for other solutions if need be, so thanks for that.